# Python script to convert strings from hex to bin contained in a txt

Tags: python, hex, decimal

I am looking for a simple script possibly in python that can:
-convert a list of 4 bytes Hexadecimal strings to Decimal

Something that would look like"
script.py infile.txt outfile.txt

Comment: We aren't a code writing service. Please show your attempts

Comment: I know only basics stuffs. But i am willing to read and learn. It looks like the function int(x,16) does the job. But x has to be a a string not a file. So I need to find out how to load the infile.txt, read first line, return the decimal value, go to the next line, do the same and write the result in outfile.txt line by line. i'll keep digging and will report back later

Comment: I'll be that guy that writes it for you. :) since you prob don't know how to program anyway

Comment: there you go did it for you. :) have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = "infile.txt"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
out = int(content, 16)

f = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(out))
f.close()
```

This is what I came up with so far... It works well if infile contains only one line... I still need to figure out to do it line by line...

Comment: That's a great start! And you also used the `with` statement which many omit; I suggest you look at `for` loops with files (hint `for line in f` iterates through the lines of `f`)

Comment: As an addendum, you would receive way less down-votes on your question if you had attempted to write this *prior* to asking and *then* posted this code along with a question that describes what your issue is. People here love to help others but only when others have shown genuine effort in trying to tackle a problem :-).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I was looking into `readline, splitlines` functions without success. I will check `for` now.

Comment: and yes, as the good idiot that I am, I was expecting someone to do it for me... Sorry about that.

Comment: It's not idiocy, it's unfamiliarity. My first question here was *immediately* closed :-). After seeing other questions and reading the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page you'll get the gist of it.